# How should I copy data between different storage groups in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

is it possible to migrate or copy the data of one storage group to another storage group, or to update storage group in Apache IoTDB? Is there any way, or any function in IoTDB that I can do this in an easy way?

I haven't found a suitable way to copy data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `SELECT INTO` statement, which can copy data from query result set into target time series in Apache IoTDB. You can also use this statement to edit the time series set to aligned device/time as you wanted.